# SQLAlchemy: create a composite primary key made of another composite primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, how can I declare a composite primary key which is made from another composite primary key ?

Let's say I have this model:

```
┌────────┐             ┌───────┐            ┌───────┐
| Person |  ── 1,n ──> |  Pet  | ── 1,n ──> |  Toy  |
├--------┤             ├-------┤            ├-------┤
|   id   |             |  age  |            | color | 
|  name  |             └───────┘            └───────┘
└────────┘
```

One person can have multiple pets, one pet can have multiple toys. So far, that's simple.

That harder part is that I want `Pet` and `Toy` to have composite primary keys:

- the primary key of `Person` is `id`
- the **composite** primary key of `Pet` is `(Person.id, Pet.age)`
- the **composite** primary key of `Toy` is `(<Pet primary key>, Toy.color)`

Where I'm struggling is to use the `<Pet primary key>` in `Toy`'s composite primary key.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)


class Pet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pet'
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('age', 'person_id', name='pet_pk'),)
    age = Column(Integer, default=0)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))


class Toy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'toy'
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('color', ???, name='toy_pk'),)
    color = Column(String)
```

As the primary key of `Pet` is a **composite** primary key, how can I use it in another **composite** primary key ?

In my `Toy` table, should I add a `pet_age` column and a `person_id` column to be able to build the `Pet` composite key, so I can reference it like this:

```
(PrimaryKeyConstraint('color', 'pet_age', 'person_id', name='toy_pk')
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

- I need to declare all the `Pet` composite primary key inside my `Toy` table
- create a new composite primary key with all these fields
- and declare a foreign key constraint with multiple fields:

```
class Toy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'toy'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('color', 'pet_age', 'person_id', name='toy_pk'),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['pet_age', 'person_id'], ['pet.age', 'pet.person_id'])
    )
    color = Column(String)
    pet_age = Column(Integer)
    person_id = Column(Integer)
```